# OSRM and car.lua change (problem to adapt)

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

We are using OSRM to calculate map matched itinerary of trucks, and until now it worked smothly.

But the restrictions on some roads in OSM are starting to create problems for our solution :

- the pedestrian zones are used by truck for deliveries (center of cities for exemple)
- some truck use track in rural area
- some street are considered private (with exceptional permit)
  and OSRM don't allow truck to use those way-id.

We've got GPS points every 30 secondes, and we can see that the vehicles are using thoses way-id, but they are not allowed by car.lua.

We tried to change the content of access_tag_blacklist and access_tag_whitelist in car.lua (adding private in white list, or commenting it in black list), and we tried to add track as a possible road type, but the script stop during the selection of usable way-id, and we are not sure to understand how to modifie the file.

Is there a documentation somewhere ?
Or does someone have solved the same issue ?

Thanks in advance,

Al